# Drupal 7 - Administration - Find node by it's field value

Tags: drupal, user-interface, interface, drupal-7, admin

I'm looking for the way for the site's administrator / moderator to find / filter the list of nodes by some field custom value. Field value could be defined by radio / text / checkbox etc.

Default content listing proposes only few filters, it's not enough for sites with huge amount of custom nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an EntityFieldQuery object, documented here:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7

The documentation has no examples (ugh), but there's a thread here with some:

http://drupal.org/node/916776

EDIT:  Ah, you're talking about administration and not actually writing a module to do it.  If that's the case, use a view with exposed filters, like the other guy said. :)

Comment: Exactly, I'm speaking only about administration of nodes, it's not a question at the moment to create the specific module.

Comment: You answered the wrong question, but this is EXACTLY what *I* needed, so hey, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it would help to use a view for it, where you set filters, so that you get the desired listing.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Probably, the disadvantage of this approach : I have lots of custom fields for different content types, it's not always the same, so I should create different custom views in each case, and, for each site, probably too. Is it possible to create the views, which will automatically expose all fields for all node types ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to test this, but I've just confirmed. Views in Drupal 7 can indeed filter across multiple content types w/ custom fields, and still have filters apply to those custom fields. They seem to treat the nodes w/o those custom fields as empty or null values.

So for instance, I have article and blog content types. Blog has images, article does not. I can sort or filter on the image field, even though article doesn't have it. It simply assumes the field is null or empty.

This however, may not solve your problem of having a large number of custom fields. If these are dynamic (i.e. they grow over time) you might be in trouble. If, however, they are set, and just a very large number, you could manage this.

So while there is no automatic add all fields, which I believe you mentioned in a previous post, you could feasibly search on a large variety of the fields. Even exposing fields that you don't necessarily display in the table, but can then search on. Or changing the fields you expose or display on a per page basis in the view. All from one view. And then you could export the view to bring it over to the other sites.

I was going to try and attach the exported view, but the export is rather large for inclusion in an answer, I think. Please let me know if you think I should still include it, or if you'd rather I can simply send it to you through a PM. Let me know!

EDIT: I decided to include a link to an export of the view. http://greggalante.com/sites/greggalante.com/files/cross_type_view.txt

Comment: If I understood correctly Your answer, to perform advanced search, we should create a view with all possible exposed fields ? If it's possible to generate such view automatically, without to re-create it for each installation ?

Comment: Basically yes. I'm not sure how usable that would be from the user perspective, but that's a different problem. There should be no limit to the number of filters or fields you can add. The only limits would be memory and processing. And you should be able to export the view, and import it into new installations. I don't know if you can do it automatically, but you might be able to. I just haven't worked with installation profiles much.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/search_api

Comment: As it's written in the description, this module provide a framework, so it's not functional ready solution to make an advanced search on some selected field.